# Upgrading from WebLogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.4 breaks our application using Spring Framework 3.0.2

Tags: spring, weblogic

Our company is having us upgrade from Oracle WebLogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.4 since 12.1.3 is out of support/going out of support.

We have a major application that is using Spring Framework v3.0.2. When we deploy the EAR to 12.2.1.4 and attempt to consume any of the web services, we get this error stack trace. I've removed names that specify our company with generic names but you should be able to get the gist of what is happening:

> 2021-06-02 15:21:50.019/27.406 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.4.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Configured versioned, multi-cluster Management over ReST
> 02.06.2021 15:22:11 - error trying to getBean("DefaultJBL"): Error creating bean with name 'DefaultJBL' defined in URL [zip:C:/javadev/server/appserver.12.2.1.4/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/lasor/2wlg44/lib/Lasor_core-1.0.jar!/com/foo/app/corebuslogic/common/jbl/DefaultJBL.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.app.corebuslogic.common.exceptions.LoggedException
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DefaultJBL' defined in URL [zip:C:/javadev/server/appserver.12.2.1.4/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/app/2wlg44/lib/App_core-1.0.jar!/com/foo/app/corebuslogic/common/jbl/DefaultJBL.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aep.lasor.corebuslogic.common.exceptions.LoggedException
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
> at com.foo.util.FOOApplicationContext.fetchBean(FOOApplicationContext.java:203)
> at com.foo.app.buslogic.common.generic.GenericSessionBean.getBL(GenericSessionBean.java:293)
> at com.foo.app.buslogic.common.generic.GenericSessionBean.query(GenericSessionBean.java:97)

I also believe the API is SOAP in 12.1.3 but I see REST specified in the 12.2.1.4 logs. Could this be the issue or am I reading that incorrectly?

Also, the classes is says it cannot find I've verified are there in the deployment area of WebLogic so I'm not sure why it can't find them.

Here is where the code throws an exception no matter what bean name I pass in but they've all been defined. The class is our FOOApplicationContext that implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware and has a fetchBean function that does the following:

```
public static Object fetchBean(final String beanName) throws FOOException {
    Object object = null;

    if (beanName == null) {
        throw new FOOException("beanName is null");
    }

    try {
         object = currentSpringContext().getBean(beanName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        final String message = "error trying to getBean('"" + beanName + "\"): " + e.getMessage();
        throw new FOOException(message, e);
    }

    return object;
}
```

When getBean() is called under WebLogic 12.1.3, it works. But it throws the AOP Exception error listed above when this exact same function is called under WebLogic 12.4.1.2. No code changes, etc. Not sure why this is.

We haven't created an actual server yet to deploy to, but instead I've installed it locally on my development machine. I've set up the database connections, etc the same way as do when locally installing 12.1.3. Is there something that has changed in regards to Spring Framework? The code was written over 8+ years ago and I inteherited the support for it and now I have to get us moved to WebLogic 12.2.1.4 before the end of this year and this is a major part of a very important application. The WebLogic application houses all the business logic and database access in it so without it, the front-end app is dead in the water.

Also, none of our registered beans will instantiate at all under WebLogic 12.2.1.4 but it works under 12.1.3. I've even recompiled the EAR file and again, it works under 12.1.3 but not 12.2.1.4.

I've found what appears to be a possibly circular reference between 2 objects that are not registered as beans, but the beans do depend on. So those 2 objects are not registered as beans. Not sure why it was done that way, but in any case, this doesn't seem to create a problem in 12.1.3. But one of the objects (FOOException) shows up in the error thrown when trying to create the DefaultJBL bean within the FOOApplicationContext object.

I'm not sure what else I can provide. Searching around the internet has not found a solution to my issue. I've found some that appeared as if they would fix it, but they turn out to not apply. I cannot seem to find anyone else with this issue, but Google and Duck Duck Go all find various "solutions" that don't apply to my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFound Exception, You may need to update the Dependencies pertaining to Spring Framework

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).